# How to return all values that appear in all 2-value tuples grouped by the other value?

Tags: sql

I need to write a SQL query that returns all the authors (aid) that have written every book (bid) stored in the dataset.

The schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    BID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    AID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (bid, aid)
);

INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Confessions of a DBA','Ada');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Confessions of a DBA','Bob');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Confessions of a DBA','Carl');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Falling in love with Relational Algebra','Ada');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Falling in love with Relational Algebra','Bob');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Falling in love with Relational Algebra','Carl');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('Falling in love with Relational Algebra','Dave');
INSERT INTO A (bid, aid) VALUES ('NULL values and me','Carl');
```

The answer to this should be 'Carl'. I'm new to SQL so I would appreciate any and all help, thanks!

Comment: What's your DB server?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to compare the number of books an author has written to the total number of books:

```
SELECT aid
FROM   (SELECT   aid, COUNT(*) AS a_cnt
        FROM     a
        GROUP BY aid) x
JOIN   (SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT bid) AS b_cnt
        FROM     a) y ON x.a_cnt = y.b_cnt
```

Comment: Your sub-query `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM a` returns the count of all records. You should do a count of select distinct bid.

Comment: @RobertKock yikes, indeed! Lost concentration there for a sec. Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to extract the authors that appear the same number of times in the table as there are book titles.
Something like this:

```
SELECT   aid,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     a
GROUP BY aid
HAVING   COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bid) FROM a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by author and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select aid
from A
group by aid
having count(distinct bid) = (select count(distinct bid) from A)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nHNoq8JJQrrPyv29cSrRBm/0).
Result:

```
| aid  |
| ---- |
| Carl |
```